# Fastening a TV Wall Mount to studs through drywall

Tags: drywall, studs

If I were mounting, say, a [TV Wall Mount](https://www.amazon.ca/Mounting-Dream-600x400mm-Centering-MD2268-LK/dp/B00NKYYMAW/)   to studs through drywall, would I need to do anything to prevent the screws from digging into the drywall?

Can I just use the screws that come with the mounting hardware, first drilling a hole through the drywall and into the wood?

Comment: I do not understand your concern about digging into the wall. Can you elaborate your concerns.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The mount itself will hold the heads of the screws, so you don't have to worry about them going into the plaster or drywall.

- Determine where the studs are (stud finder, knocking on the wall, drilling small holes - whatever method works for you).
- Mark the locations using the mount itself or a template. Use a level to make sure that the holes are lined up properly.
- Predrill holes, approximately the size of the body (without the threads) of the screws.
- Hold the mount on the wall and screw in the screws. If you have a helper then this is really easy. If you are doing this by yourself, screw one screw in enough so that it will safely hold the mount, then screw in the second screw, double-check the positioning and then screw both screws all the way into the studs.

As far as which screws to use, that depends. A good mount often comes with multiple sets of fasteners for drywall + studs, drywall by itself (though I don't recommend that) and masonry. If you use the wrong fastener, it will **not** be secure/safe. For drywall + studs, I recommend screws between 2" and 3" long, so if it comes with little 1" or even 1-1/2" screws, you may want to use larger screws.