# Using a VESA mount across a 30" gap

Tags: studs, television

I'm considering mounting my TV in a location where there is ~30" between studs (*because there's a window there*).

Would it be okay to use a VESA mount such as

[this one](https://www.newegg.ca/startech-com-fpwtltbat-low-profile-tv-mount/p/N82E16886949046?Description=vesa&cm_re=vesa-_-86-949-046-_-Product)

across such a gap?

Or is it important to have screws in the studs near the point where the TV rests on the mount beam?

Comment: Is this question about a different tv mount in different location then the question you asked earlier?  https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/207148/fastening-a-tv-wall-mount-to-studs-through-drywall  **Are you saying you want to span the window opening with tv mount?**

Comment: @AlaskaMan It's about mounting in the same location but about different aspects of the plan.  Yes, I want to span the window opening with the tv mount.

Comment: If the question is about the same tv and mount then combine both into one question with all the pertinent info and avoid duplicate questions. both question are lacking in details that are important to providing an informed answer.

Comment: For the record, I disagree with the advice provided by @Alaska to combine your questions into a single one. It is perfectly fine, and even expected, that if you have _different_ questions then, even if they relate to the same project, you will post them as separate posts. That is in fact the main reason for the "Needs focus" close reason, which advises to reduce a post to a _single question_, posting a new question for any additional questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's actually hard to say for sure where the framing is around the window opening, different for common residential framing and commercial construction, etc.

You say the window opening is 30" so let's say the jack studs  are 36" apart.  According to the page you linked, the mount is about 39" wide, and it looks like the outermost mounting holes are about 37" apart, so it would just barely work.  If there are any miscalculations, you could have a headache.

Consider this, if there's molding around the window, you'll want to put something behind the mount so it clears the window, maybe a piece of 3/4" plywood that's the same height as the mount.

If you make that piece of plywood a little wider - say 6" wide - you can attach that first, hit the studs with the plywood with several screws, then attach the mount to the plywood.  This gives you some flexibility.

Comment: The window opening is actually about an inch and a half smaller than that—I was measuring between the centerpoints of where the studs are if they're located on either side of the window.  I was [led to believe](https://www.bobvila.com/articles/how-to-find-a-wall-stud/) that there are always studs on either side of a window.  The window is actually sunk back into the wall so I think it should be easy to mount to studs if they're located next to the window.  I'm mostly just not sure if the mount will have the tensile strength to support weight centered between widely spaced bolts.

Comment: There usually is a little space between the window casing and the studs around the window opening, that space is often stuffed with insulation or expanding foam and is concealed behind trim.

Comment: Most any half decent  mount will be fine with four lags in the four corners suspended across the opening.

Answer (score 1):

When in doubt, [RTFM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RTFM):

[StarTech Low-Profile TV Wall Mount - Tilting Manual](https://sgcdn.startech.com/005329/media/sets/fpwtltbat_manual/fpwtltbat_wall_mount_tilt_anti-theft_manual.pdf)

Product dimensions page clearly shows *min 300 mm to max 810 mm*.

30" = 762mm

300 < 762 < 810

<s>That works. You're good to go!</s>

Oops. As pointed out by OP, that is for the VESA bracket. The wall bracket is actually wider than that, 985mm. You can't go all the way to the edge, but based on the diagram, the usable holes on the wall bracket are clearly wider than the 810mm of the VESA bracket. So that still works out OK.

Comment: Those dimensions are for the VESA mount point on the back of the TV and are not related to my question.

Answer (score 1):

Another option is to install a cleat into the studs and then use any VESA TV mount you want by connecting it to the cleat.  This is one way of installing kitchen cabinets, too.  Search Youtube for *french cleat kitchen cabinet installation* for many excellent examples.